# How to turn an array of indices into a binary 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have array of vertices from an stl file which i converted to a 2D numpy array. Here's some of it as an example:

```
print(vertices.shape)

(67748, 3)
```

I need to turn these into a 3D binary array where each element = 1 where the index is given by the vertices array.

Minimal reproducible example (expected output) using a 5 x 3 vertices array instead of 67748 x 3:

```
verts = np.array([[ 77, 239,  83],
 [100, 237,  88],
 [100, 149,  94],
 [100, 220, 128],
 [100, 145,  86]])

voxels = np.zeros((256,256,256)).astype(int)

voxels[77,239,83] = 1
voxels[100,149,94] = 1
voxels[100,237,88] = 1
voxels[100,220,128] = 1
voxels[100,145, 86] = 1
```

Comment: Could you should an example of the expecting output please

Comment: `voxel_array[tuple(vertices.T)] = 1`. Please provide a copyable [mre]. The `for` loop solution is not correct.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with the example

Comment: `for x, y, z in vertices: voxel_array[x, y, z] = 1` would be a solution with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.put` and `np.ravel_multi_index`

```
np.put(voxel_array, 
       np.ravel_multi_index(vertices.T, 
                            voxel_array.shape), 
       1)
```

And then:

```
np.where(voxel_array)
Out[]: 
(array([ 77, 100, 100, 100, 100], dtype=int64),
 array([239, 145, 149, 220, 237], dtype=int64),
 array([ 83,  86,  94, 128,  88], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Michael Szczesny in the comments:

for x, y, z in vertices: voxel_array[x, y, z] = 1

This works just as well as Daniel F's but is easier to understand. Both take 0.0 seconds to run on 256 x 265 x 265 array